# jQuery UI slider not showing in IE9 (not a trailing comma)

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, internet-explorer-9, jquery-ui-slider

My jQuery UI slider works fine in chrome, FF  and IE10, but when it comes to IE9 slider doesnt even show up

Heres a sample of slider call:

```
$( "#slider-range-min-amount" ).slider({
  range: "min",
  value: castka,
  min: 500,
  max: 5000,
  slide: function( event, ui ) {
    $( "#amount" ).val( ui.value + " Kč" );
    $( "#amountsend" ).val( ui.value );
    spoctiKlientVrati();
  },
  step: 500
});
```

http://ideone.com/x22RMC (the whole original script check line 9 and beneath)

Anyone knows what might cause this problem?

**EDIT** versions:  jQuery v1.9.1 + jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js , jQuery UI - v1.10.3

ps: sorry no double call, I misslooked other one was css :)

**EDIT 2** I finally unistalled IE10 update to fall back to IE9 now my IE9 is showing the sliders but http://netrenderer.com/ wont show them and shows some error - screen: http://pbrd.co/1dbbaaG - so I guess client's IE9 wont show it too :/

Comment: I commented console.logs & - even it should be the same - rewrote the $() to $(document).ready() and will contact the client wether it fixed problem on his build of IE9 ... I will come back with client response :)

Comment: Strange thing happened today IE Renderer started to render IE9 version  correctly and showed sliders - however my IE9 itself didnt show them - at the first time - but after F5 it did show them .... strange IE ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take away console.log. I find this causes issues in IE9 (this is because console does not become defined in IE9 until you open up the developer tools)

I can see at least one instance of it at the very bottom in your else statement.

**EDIT: And another one near the top**

Also check to make sure the version of IE you're running in isn't in quirks mode or something incompatible with jQuery. You can do this by opening the IE developer tools with f12 and in the menus at the top, on the far right you can select the document mode. Make sure this is set to IE9 standards.

Comment: Note: funny thing - IE10 set to IE9 display with IE9standards shows slider , but IE9 itself does not :), will check the console :)

Comment: IE standards are a funny thing. Hope I was able to help.

Comment: What version of jQuery and jQuery UI are you using? (If it's below 1.8.6 there are known issues, you may need to upgrade)

Comment: Do you get any errors in the IE developer console when you load the page? Also do you declare the slider code within $(document).ready(function(){

});?